# UserForm and Range

Tags: excel, vba, range, userform, worksheet

I have an Excel sheet with column D (column 4) being a dropdown list for every row with 2 choices :

- Yes
- No

When I click No, I have a Userform pop up with a simple "text zone" asking to enter a value and a "Submit button" to validate.

When the "Submit button" is clicked, I want the value from the "text zone" to be implemented into the cell to the right : offset(0,1).

Example : D5 : "No" -> "Enters 5 in Userform" -> E5: "5"

Here is my code so far :

Worksheet :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If ActiveCell.Column = 4 Then
        If ActiveCell.Value = "no" Then
            UserForm1.Show
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

UserForm :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
    UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
```

If I put the UserForm1.Hide before the ActiveCell it does what I want but the UserForm won't close.
If I take out the ActiveCell the UserForm closes but I can't seem to make both work at once.

Comment: because your code is caught  into event loop. Learn and use `Application.EnableEvents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing cells *in the Worksheet_Change handler*, which means if you didn't have a form to block the UI, you'd quickly blow the call stack and run into an "Out of stack space" error, also known as a... *stack overflow*.

You need to prevent your `Worksheet_Change` handler from calling itself recursively.

And this can be done by turning off `Application.EnableEvents` before you make the change, and toggling it back on afterwards:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Now, see what the problem is with that? How does the form know that it's being invoked from a `Worksheet_Change` handler and so that it needs to toggle `Application.EnableEvents`? It *doesn't* know - and right now, it's *assuming* it.

This is a problem, only because *the form is running the show*. Flip things around, and leave the form as stupid as it can possibly be, and make the `Worksheet_Change` handler responsible for making the sheet changes *and* toggling the`Application.EnableEvents` state:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 And Not IsError(Target.Value) Then
        If Target.Value = "no" Then
            With New UserForm1
                .Show
                If .Proceed Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = .Contents
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Several things:

1. The cell that triggered the event is the `Target` - use *that* over `ActiveCell`.
2. If the value of that cell is `#N/A` or any other cell error value, your code blows up. Use `IsError` to verify whether it's safe to compare the cell's value with anything first.
3. The form now needs `Proceed` and `Contents` properties, and can't be allowed to self-destruct.
4. The calling code doesn't care about any textboxes: it doesn't know how `Contents` is getting populated - that's the form's concern.

So what would the form's code-behind look like now?

```
Option Explicit
Private mProceed As Boolean
Private mContents As String

Public Property Get Proceed() As Boolean
    Proceed = mProceed
End Property

Public Property Get Contents() As String
    Contents = mContents
End Property

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    mContents = TextBox1.value
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    mProceed = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

Now all the form does, is collect data, and expose it for the calling code to see: it doesn't know or care about any `ActiveCell` or worksheet - it collects data, and exposes it for the calling code to see. *Nothing more, nothing less*.