# Write values from TextBox of a VBA Userform to Excel Cells

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I currently have a userform that is supposed to autopopulate the data that is typed into the textboxes and listboxes into the next available row in on my Sheet1. Currently, only the listboxes are populating once I press my Submit button. Please help my debug my textboxes, which are name as txt___

Comment: It would be really helpful, if you delete 70% of your code, which is non-relevant to the textboxes.

Comment: Yeah, was abotu to say - theyre not being set b/c you literally dont set them

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50913031/1188513) from 3 minutes ago explains how you can cleanly do what your question title says (didn't read the wall of code).

Comment: If I delete the part relevant to the listboxes, then how will they copy to the worksheet? Also, how do I set them @Doug Coats? Sorry, I am new to VBA

Comment: Removing *all* the code doesn't make a [mcve]...

Answer (score 1):

If you try only this, would it work:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Submit_Click()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.txtCompany.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.txtPOC.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.txtPhone.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.txtEmail.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.Contract.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.Capability.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.Agency.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.txtDepartment.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.Socioeconomic.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.txtNotes.Value
    End With

End Sub
```

The change is that I refer to the `Me`, thinking that your code is in the `Form`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Could it be that I have too many Dim's? I'm struggling to find a solution

Comment: @AggieTAM - which part did not work? Is the code in a form?

Comment: The code is in a form. adding the "me's" gave me the same result that I have been having, where I type in a value into the textboxes, and it does not get copied to the worksheet

Comment: @AggieTAM - are you sure that you are lookcing at the correct worksheet? `Sheet1`?

Comment: @AggieTAM adding the "me's" is only giving you the same result *because you're invoking the form's default instance* - call the form with `frm = New UserForm2` and then do `frm.Show` and watch your code fall apart, whereas with these `Me` qualifiers you're always referring to the correct instance of the form. Not the same at all.